# Jquery - Función CheckFileName devuelve Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagen, modal

a través de 3 funciones Jquery cargo imágenes en una ventana Modal para posteriormente subirlas a un directorio del servidor y actualizar la base de datos. Este proceso funciona correctamente.

El problema que se me presenta es a la hora de chequear los ficheros, en concreto lo que hago es comparar el nombre del fichero seleccionado con los nombres de ficheros que recupero del windows Modal, es decir, subo la imagen 1.png a la ventana modal al no haber otra imagen llamada 1.png la muestra si ya estuviera en la ventana mostraría un mensaje de error tipo este nombre de fichero ya esta en la ventana.

Utilizo el siguiente código JQuery:

```
      function appendImage(file) {

          var picReader = new FileReader();

          picReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {

                    var picFile = event.target;

                        checkMeasure(file, picFile, function(resp){

                            if(resp){
                                var imageBox = $("<div class='box-image-library box-image-library-upload' id='box-image-library'> \
                                                    <img class='image-library' id='fileImageLibrary'/> \
                                                    <div class='btn-image-library-delete'> \
                                                      <button class='btn-image-library' data-action='delete'><i class='material-icons' style='font-size: 20px'>delete</i></button> \
                                                    </div> \
                                                    <div class='box-text-image-library-upload'> \
                                                      <span class='text-descripcio-image-library' id='text-descripcio-image-library'></span> \
                                                    </div> \
                                                  </div>");

                                // Insert Element in Box Content
                                $('#imagesUploadContent').append(imageBox);

                                // Set src img, filename and modify id elements
                                $('#fileImageLibrary').attr('src', picFile.result);
                                $('#text-descripcio-image-library').text(file.name);

                                $('#box-image-library').attr('id', 'box-image-library-' + file.name);
                                $('#fileImageLibrary').attr('id', 'fileImageLibrary-' + file.name);
                                $('#text-descripcio-image-library').attr('id', 'text-descripcio-image-library-' + file.name);

                            }else{
                              alert('La imatge ' + file.name + ' sobrepasa els limits permesos');
                            }
                        });


          });

          //Read the image
          picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }

      document.getElementById('filesUpload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);


      function handleFileSelect() {

            //Check File API support
            if (!window.File || !window.FileList || !window.FileReader) {
                console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
                return;
            }

            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            var output = document.getElementById("result");

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

                var file = files[i];
                //Only pics
                if (!file.type.match('image')) continue;

                  if (checkFileName(file)){

                      if(checkSize(file)){

                          appendImage(file);
                      }
                  }
            }
      }

      // Check the name to compare with others files in modal window

      function checkFileName(file){

          var name = file.name;

          // Recorrer todos los elementos actuales .box-image-library
          if ( $('.box-image-library-upload')[0] ) {                        // Si existe uno.

              $('.box-image-library-upload').each(function(i, obj) {

                  var fileNameModal = $( this ).find('.text-descripcio-image-library').text();

                  if (name == fileNameModal){     // Hay un elemento cargado en la ventana Modal con el mismo $estado_nombre
                      alert('No pots pujar un fitxer amb el mateix nom.');
                      return false;

                  }else{          // No existe ese fichero en la ventana Modal con lo cual es nuevo/diferente
                      return true;
                  }
              });


          }else{
            return true;
          }
      }


    // Functions to check images LIBRARY

    function checkSize(file){

        var size = file.size;

        if (size > 1048576){
            alert('La imatge: ' + file.name + ' es sobrepasa del límit permès.');
            return false;

        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    function checkMeasure(file, picFile, cb){

      var image = new Image();

      image.src = picFile.result;

      image.onload = function() {
                    // Allow image size
                    if(this.width < 301 && this.height < 301){
                        cb(true);
                    }else{
                        cb(false);
                    }
                };
    }
```

El principal problema lo tengo a la hora de comparar ya que no me devuelve ni true ni false de la función checkFileName estoy seguro que debe estar relacionado con los eventos que se lanzan pero ahora mismo estoy en un punto muerto.

Si me pudierais aconsejar estaría agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el `return` lo estás haciendo dentro de la función del método `each` de jQuery. El método `each` ignora cualquier valor devuelto diferente de `false` y, en caso de que la función devuelva `false` simplemente detiene la iteración.

Mira estos ejemplos:

```js
var datos = [1, 2, 4, 10, 20, 40];

function ejemplo1(){
  // Cuando encuentra un elemento >=15 detiene la iteración
  $(datos).each(function(x){
    console.log(datos[x]);
    return datos[x]<15;
  });
  // No devuelve nada
}

function ejemplo2(){
  var encontrado = false;
  // Si encuentra un elemento >=15 detiene la iteración y
  // activa el flag encontrado
  $(datos).each(function(x){
    console.log(datos[x]);
    if (datos[x]>=15){
      encontrado = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
  // Devuelve si ha encontrado un valor >15
  return encontrado;
}

$(function(){
  $('#ejemplo1').click(function(){
    console.log('Resultado ejemplo 1: ', ejemplo1());
  });
    $('#ejemplo2').click(function(){
    console.log('Resultado ejemplo 2: ', ejemplo2());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ejemplo1">Ejemplo 1</button>
<button id="ejemplo2">Ejemplo 2</button>
```

Comment: Entiendo, entonces la manera en que lo he planteado si añadiera un conjunto de imágenes y encontrara coincidencia con una de ellas se acabaría el bucle i dejaría de analizar las siguientes.

Comment: Eso es. Dejaría de analizar las siguientes pero la función externa (`checkFileName`) no devolvería ningún valor.